Some shortcuts like Type Hierarchy not working in PhpStorm in WSL environment
I am using PhpStorm in a WSL environment. I have Ubuntu installed in WSL. Some of the shortcuts like Ctrl + H (Type Hierarchy) or Ctrl + Alt + H (Call Hierarchy) or Ctrl + Shift + H (Method Hierarchy) are not working.
I tried setting different keymaps, none of them worked. I also tried setting a new shortcut for Type Hierarchy action, but it did not work either.
Does anyone have any solution for this? Same shortcuts work if I open phpstorm and open projects on my windows machine(not wsl).
